# Generic Nullable Enum

Tags: c#, generics, enums, nullable

I would like to have a method that will parse from a nullable database column an enum.
I wrote this method below (and had to restrict T to a struct to make it compile).

It does compile, but I believe its wrong as Enums are not structs?
If so, how do I restrict the generic method to say I am expecting a ValueType you don't have to complain at me that "Only non-nullable value type could be underlying of 'System.Nullable'

```
private static T? ParseEnum<T>(DataRow row, string columnName)
    where T : struct
{
    T? value = null;
    try
    {
        if (row[columnName] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            value = (T)Enum.Parse(
                typeof(T),
                row[columnName].ToString(),
                true);
        }
    }

    catch (ArgumentException) { }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Enums are just ints with sugar on top, so they are indeed structs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no constraint available in C# that allows you to restrict that a given type is an enum. In IL there's such notion though. Jon [blogged about it](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/09/10/generic-constraints-for-enums-and-delegates.aspx).

Comment: and also enums are actually structs

Comment: @Artiom enum actyally is a CLASS! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try to use dynamic and create generic list of enum at runtime

```
    public static dynamic ToValues(this Type enumType)
    {
        var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType);
        Type list = typeof(List<>);
        Type resultType = list.MakeGenericType(enumType);
        dynamic result =  Activator.CreateInstance(resultType);
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            dynamic concreteValue = Enum.Parse(enumType, value.ToString());
            result.Add(concreteValue);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

As a result you'll have List of concrete enum